# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to upload some excel file data in my application. From my local system (Windows 7) my code is working fine. But after hosting in server (2003), when I am trying to upload a file (.xlsx) I am getting an error - System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

My code :

```
         try
         {
             string connectionString = "";
             if (fuUpload.HasFile)
             {                  

                 string fileName = "_uploadTemp";
                 string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fuUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                 string fileLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FileUpload/" + fileName + fileExtension);
                 fuUpload.SaveAs(fileLocation);

                 lbl1.Text = "File Saved";

                 //Check whether file extension is xls or xslx

                 if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                 {
                     connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                 }
                 else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                 {
                     connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                 }
                 lbCon.Text = connectionString;
                 //  Create OleDB Connection and OleDb Command

                 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                 cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                 cmd.Connection = con;
                 OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                 DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();


                 con.Open();

                 lbl2.Text = "Connection open";

                 //DataSet dtExcelSheetName=con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbDataAdapter.DefaultSourceTableName,null);
                 DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                 string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                 dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                 dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
                 // dtExcelRecords = RemoveDuplicate(dtExcelRecords, "nOdc_Wwid");
                 con.Close();
                 lbl3.Text = "Connection Closed";
                 DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();
                 dttemp.Columns.Add("sOdc_People_Name", typeof(string));
                 dttemp.Columns.Add("vEmailId", typeof(string));
                 dttemp.Columns.Add("nOdc_Wwid", typeof(int));
                 dttemp.Columns.Add("Vpnaccess", typeof(string));//
                 dttemp.Columns.Add("Details", typeof(string));


                 for (int i = 0; i < dtExcelRecords.Rows.Count; i++)
                 {

                     dttemp.Rows.Add(dtExcelRecords.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dtExcelRecords.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                     dtExcelRecords.Rows[i][2].ToString(), dtExcelRecords.Rows[i][3].ToString(), dtExcelRecords.Rows[i][4].ToString());
                 }

                 Session.Add("dtTemp", dttemp);//Created temp session to store the excel data

                 lbl4.Text = "Data added to temp table";


                 if (dttemp.Rows.Count <= 0)
                 {
                     gvMain.DataSource = mailutility.GetTempDataSetX("sOdc_People_Name", "vEmailId", "nOdc_Wwid", "Vpnaccess", "Details");
                     gvMain.DataBind();
                     gvMain.Rows[0].Visible = false;

                 }
                 else
                 {

                     gvMain.DataSource = dttemp;
                     gvMain.DataBind();
                     lnkConfirm.Visible = true;
                     lnkCancelC.Visible = true;
                     pnlLegend.Visible = true;
                     pnlLagendText.Visible = true;
                     mpX.Show();
                     lbl5.Text = "Grid binded";
                     foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvMain.Rows)
                     {
                         CheckBox chkSelect = gvMain.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
                         Label lblNameX = gvMain.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("lblNameX") as Label;
                         Label lblEmailidX = gvMain.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("lblEmailidX") as Label;
                         Label lblWwIdX = gvMain.Rows[gvr.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lblWwIdX") as Label;

                         if (lblNameX.Text != "" && IsValidEmail(lblEmailidX.Text) == true && ValidWWId(lblWwIdX.Text) == true)
                         {
                             chkSelect.Checked = true;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             chkSelect.Checked = false;
                             chkSelect.Enabled = false;
                             gvr.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                         }
                         //Check for duplicate WWID
                         for (int i = 0; i < dttemp.Rows.Count; i++)
                         {
                             if (i != gvr.RowIndex)
                             {
                                 if (dttemp.Rows[i]["nOdc_Wwid"].ToString() == lblWwIdX.Text)
                                 {
                                     chkSelect.Checked = false;
                                     chkSelect.Enabled = false;
                                     gvr.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }


                 }

             }
         }
         catch (Exception es)
         {
             lbException.Text = es.ToString();
         }
```

Please some one help me.

Gulrej

Answer (score 3):

1.Try to download this from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

2.Go to Visual Studio click add data source, follow the wizard.

This is the same problem I had before and followed steps from here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

***You need to install the `x86 version` if the target machine is `32 bit` or the `x64 version` if the target machine is `64 bit` and your application is built with configuration Any CPU.***

Comment: I am trying to upload data from excel file. Will it work for this as well.

Comment: I need to install this to the server or in my local system?

Comment: you need to instal it on your local system

Comment: Still I am getting the same Error : System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local

Comment: Try doing this go to project properties, Build Option --> set the Platform Target X86. and may b this also helps you http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/78/AccessDataSource-SqlDataSource-and-connecting-to-Access-databases-in-ASP.NET

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24746/discussion-between-gulrej-and-coder)

Comment: For Amazon EC2, I installed the redistributable via Remote Desktop and that worked. I couldn't get the Amazon deploy to include it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to check is your build configuration of your application.

- If you have **built your project under x86 platform**, then in order to
  resolve you issue you should install the following packages on your
  machine:

  1. In order to use the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider you must
     **install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable**
     first, this installation is available at:
     http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255 .

     After the installation has complete, try running you application, if this
     solves the issue great, if not, continue to step 2.
  2. This next step is an unexplained workaround, which works for Office
     2010, even though it is the Data Connectivity Components of Office 2007.  I am not quite sure why this works, but it does and this has been proven to work in almost all cases. You need to **install the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components**, this installation is available at:
     http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 .

     After this installation is complete, try running your application, this should resolve the issue.
- If you are trying to run an **application built under x64 or AnyCPU
  platform**, I would recommend first validating that it runs as expected
  under the x86 platform.  In the event that it does not run under that
  x86 platform, perform the steps in the first part and validate that
  it runs as expected.

  I did read that the MS Access drivers including the OLEDB Database
  driver works only under the x86 platform and is incompatible under
  the x64 or AnyCPU platform.  But this appears to be untrue. I
  validated my application was running when building x86, then I
  installed the Access Database Engine using the passive flag.

  1. First download the file locally You can download the installation
     here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
  2. Installing using the command prompt with the '/passive' flag.   **In
     the command prompt run the following command:
     'AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive'**

  After these 2 steps I managed to run my application after building in
  x64 or AnyCPU build configuration.  This appeared to solve my issue.

Note: The order of the steps seems to make a difference, so please follow accordingly.